# Ember Data Save method, Create vs update

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-data

I can't figure out how Ember determines if it should update or create a record. I would assume its based on the ID or on the Store entry, but it seems to be something else. The code example clarifies:

```
// this returns the user without making an api call
currentUser.get('store').find('user_detail', '49')

// this returns 49
currentUser.get('id')

// this returns true
currentUser.get('store').hasRecordForId('user_detail', 49)

// this issues a create to api/userDetails instead
// of updating /api/userDetails/49
currentUser.save()

// maybe this is a lead, not the 48 at the end
currentUser.toString()
// <EmberApp.UserDetail:ember461:48>

// it looks as though currentState is involved here
// http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RootState.html
currentUser.currentState

// returns root.loaded.created.uncommitted
currentUser.get('currentState.stateName');

// also isNew is wrong and returns true
currentUser.get('isNew');
```

Let me explain why I have this issue. My app has a current user. If you logout I update the current user. So I set Ember.currentUser.setProperties(newUserData). I update the currentUser object so that ember automatically triggers updates throughout my app. If I would replace the currentUser Ember.currentUser = newUser; Nothing would update. If I cant solve the above problem an alternative solution for the swapping of the user object would also work.

This is how I handle the global user state

```
container.register('user:current', Ember.currentUser);
// and handle updates via Ember.currentUser.setProperties()
application.inject('controller', 'user', 'user:current');
application.inject('route', 'user', 'user:current');
```

A proper solution would replace Ember.currentUser, however doing that doesnt trigger updates.

Comment: Are you running all of this synchronously?  Just like it's shown?

Comment: Yes, this is synchronous.

Answer (score 2):

A new model will have the `isNew` and `isDirty` properties set to true, an existing record that needs to be updated will only have `isDirty` set to true.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that helps a bit. Any idea on how to set isNew as its a read only propert.

Comment: @Thierry I would have currentUser set on the `ApplicationController`, or on it's own controller. That way `ApplicationController.set('currentUser', null);` will trigger any bindings.

Comment: Yes I could set it on the ApplicationController and changing it changes the bindings. The thing is I need to change it on all controllers.

Comment: I clarified the application injection in the question

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend pushing your user one level deeper and not storing it on the Ember namespace, that way you can set it from anywhere else, yet still inject it during  injection

```
var users = Em.Object.create({
  current: currentUser
});

container.register('users:current', users, {instantiate: false});
// and handle updates via Ember.currentUser.setProperties()
application.inject('controller', 'users', 'users:current');
application.inject('route', 'users', 'users:current');
```

Then from any controller you can access/watch it on `users.current`, yet you can also set it using `this.users.set('current', newUser)` which would effect anyone watching that property on any controller or route.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1145/edit

Additionally a lot of things you are doing are async calls and should use the promise pattern for viewing properties etc.