# How to properly inject property into controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

this was my initial approach but I get an error
code:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
name: "currentUser",

initialize: function(container, application) {
    var store = container.lookup('store:main'),
    attributes = $("meta[name='current-user']").attr('content');

if(attributes){
  var object = store.push(App.User, JSON.parse(attributes)),
      user   = App.User.find(object.id),
      controller = container.lookup('controller:currentUser').set('content', user);

  container.typeInjection('controller', 'currentUser', 'controller:currentUser');
  }
 }
});
```

Error:

```
Error: Cannot inject a `controller:current-user` on other controller(s). Register the `controller:current-user` as a different type and perform the typeInjection.
```

So I have tried a few other approaches since

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
name: "currentUser",
after: "store",

initialize: function(container, application) {

    var store, user, proxy;
    var attributes = $("meta[name='current-user']").attr('content');
    if (attributes) {
        application.deferReadiness();
        container.lookup('store:main').find('user', object.id).then(function(user) {
        application.register('user:current', user, { instantiate: false, singleton: true });
        application.inject('route', 'currentUser', 'user:current');
        application.inject('controller', 'currentUser', 'user:current');
        application.advanceReadiness();
    }, function() {
         application.advanceReadiness();
      }
    });
   }
 }
});
```

this doesn't throw any errors but also doesn't seem to work properly

the other approach I tried was this

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
name: "currentUser",
after: "store",

initialize: function(container, application) {

    var store, user, proxy;
    var attributes = $("meta[name='current-user']").attr('content');
    if(attributes) {
        application.deferReadiness();
        store = container.lookup('store:main');
        proxy = App.CurrentUserObjectProxy.extend();
        container.register('user:current', proxy, {singleton: true});
        proxy = container.lookup('user:current');
        var object = store.push(App.User, JSON.parse(attributes))
        store.find('user', object.id).then(function (user) {

            proxy.set('content', user);

            application.inject('controller', 'currentUser', 'user:current');

            application.advanceReadiness();
        });
       }
      }
    });
```

in a different file

```
App.CurrentUserObjectProxy = Ember.ObjectProxy.extend({
content: null
});
```

What I am trying to do to debug this issue is log the name of the currentUser on the application template

```
{{log currentUser.firstName}}
```

I can see in my ember inspector that the data for the user is getting added properly, it just isn't setting the currentUser property on controller properly, any tips of what I should be doing differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling find already returns an `ObjectProxy` so you can just call `find` and set that in your injector.

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: "currentUser",
  after: "ember-data",

  initialize: function(container, application) {

    var store, user, proxy;
    var attributes = {id:1, name:'foo'};

    if(attributes) {
        store = container.lookup('store:main');
        store.push('user', attributes);
        var user = store.find('user', attributes.id);
        container.register('user:current', user, {singleton: true, instantiate:false});
        application.inject('controller', 'currentUser', 'user:current');
     }
   }
 });
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1144/edit

If you want to be able to swap it out at some future day you can use a pattern (mentioned in my answer) found here [Ember Data Save method, Create vs update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258352/ember-data-save-method-create-vs-update/26262296#26262296)

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1145/edit

Comment: Curious why the `if (attributes)`? Should the programmer be worried that the JavaScript run time won't perform `var attributes = {...};` correctly?

Comment: I copied and pasted from the question, my guess is `attributes` is really the result of a different function which may return `undefined`/`null`.